# facing difficulty to reading complex xml file using libxml2 in c++

Tags: c++

this is my xml file

```
<Example>
     <text-frame name="SingleLineText 1" id="Text0"    wrapping="true" direction="" suppress-  empty-lines="false">
<style-ref name="default"/>
<style name="">
<alignment halign="left" valign="top"/>
<text-style text-color="Color 0" position="normal"/>
<font family-name="Times New Roman" size="14" style="Bold Italic"/>
<paragraph-style text-align="left"/>
</style>
<geometry size="absolute" position="absolute">
<location left="35" top="30"/>
<size width="165" height="45"/>
</geometry>
<condition name="" desc="">
<if>
<expression left="record1/@field3" operator="==" right="'1240 CrocoDoc Lane'"/>
<action-list>
<action type="suppress"/>
</action-list>
</if>
</condition>
<paragraph>
<style>
<paragraph-style indent-left="0" indent-right="0" indent-first="0" indent-hanging="0" line-spacing="multiple"    line-spacing-at="1.2" text-align="left"/>
</style>
<text>

<style>
<font family-name="Times New Roman" size="14" style="Bold Italic"/>
<text-style text-color="Color 0" highlight="None" position="normal" character-spacing="0" case="normal"/>
</style>
<content><![CDATA[%(record1/@field3)]]></content>
</text>
</paragraph>
</text-frame> 
</Example>
```

***and my code to reading and writing is below.*
what i want is to reach at the alignment tag using this and make change.. "/Example/text-frame/style/alignment" xpathexpression but its not working**

```
xmlXPathObject * xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression( (xmlChar*)"/Example/text-frame/style/alignment", xpathCtx );
    //xmlXPathObject * xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression( (xmlChar*)"/Example/Objects/Pet", xpathCtx );
    if ( xpathObj == NULL ) throw "failed to evaluate xpath";

for(int i=0;i<=1; i++)
    {
    xmlNode *node = NULL;
    if ( xpathObj->nodesetval && xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab )
        {
        node = xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab[i];
        std::cout << "Found the node we want" << std::endl;
        }
    else
        {throw "failed to find the expected node";}

    xmlAttr *attr = node->properties;
    while ( attr )
        {
        std::cout << "Attribute name: " << attr->name << "  value: " << attr->children->content << std::endl;
        attr = attr->next;
        }


    xmlSetProp( node, (xmlChar*)"age", (xmlChar*)"3" );

    }
```

Comment: is your XML valid? http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: how to check it? is it valid or not ?

Comment: yes it is valid i checked it from "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp" and found no error..

Comment: you look for `textframe` but you have `text-frame`

Comment: i mistakenly paste my old expresion while i was playing with it to do somthing so i correct it and founding the same error :